# Cognos Report-need 2nd (Totals) Crosstab that is "aware" (filters) using the current Grouping

Tags: reporting, cognos-10

I am trying to create a report which groups on a column called "Legal Entity." When the output is directed to Excel, a separate tab will be created for each distinct entity in the query resultset.
For each Excel tab/Legal Entity, there will be two "sections." The first is a repeating section that breaks on a column "Funding Arrangement Type." After all of the Funding Arrangement Types are exhausted, there will be a single "Totals" grid which will summarize the data on the tab for the current Legal Entity. The data will be summarized across all Funding Arrangement Types within the current Legal Entity.

Because the Totals (lower) grid is really just a summarization of the same source query, Query1, I thought that I would also bind the Totals grid to it. However, if I do that, I get a run time error that tells me that I need to establish a Master-Detail relationship (If I decide to use a separate query for the Totals grid, the Totals grid "will not be aware" of the current Legal Entity/tab that must be considered when summarizing.)

Therefore, I continued with my guess at how the Master-Detail relationship should be defined. I made various attempts to link the two grids, including:

1. On all of the dimension (non-summarized) columns.
2. On Legal Entity
3. On Legal Entity and Funding Arrangement Type

Doing so affected previously correct totals reported in the upper cross tab results/
This Master-Detail approach is foreign and as a result I don't understand what it is doing.
I also tried to use a separate query, Query2, for the lower totals grid and adding a filter to filter SQL2 where SQL2. LegalEntity = SQL1.LegalEntity in an effort to get the totals grid to summarize within the current LeglEntity grouping. This resulted in a cross join error.

I’m a real noob with Cognos. Suggestions are welcomed. Thank you!

You can use mouse+scroll wheel to zoom in:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by binding both grids to a single query and for *both* grids, establish a Master-Detail Replationship on Legal Entity. Prior to doing that, I added these columns to both grids and hide them, not sure if this was necessary.